# Count total values for given month

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this mySQL statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(clicks) FROM ads.statz WHERE user_id = '$_SESSION[user_id]'
```

Works fine it counts all the number of clicks with the given user id. What I am after is being able to group together the numbers for each month as a total. I need this for both Clicks and impressions.

Here is the layout of the DB.

```
CREATE TABLE `statz` (
  `ad_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `clicks` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `impressions` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Thanks!

Comment: **warning** your code maybe vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`MONTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) and [`YEAR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) with `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(clicks) 
FROM 
    ads.statz 
WHERE 
    user_id = '$_SESSION[user_id]' 
GROUP BY
    MONTH(date),
    YEAR(date)
```

Comment: That only counts the number of rows what I want to do is count all the values for the click column for the specific user for each month.

Comment: Just as I refreshed the page I found that out! Thanks for the help :)